# adler-32 algorithm example Clarity would be great

Tags: c#, checksum

I am having a hard time understanding what exactly is going on behind this algorithm. So, I have the following code which I believe works for the Wikipedia example. I seem to be having problems matching up the correct outcomes of hex values. While for the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) example I get the correct hex value, It seems that my `int finalValue;` is not the correct value.

```
string fText, fileName, output;
    Int32 a = 1 , b = 0;
    const int MOD_ADLER = 65521;
    const int ADLER_CONST2 = 65536;

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        fileName = tbFilePath.Text;

        if(fileName != "" && File.Exists(fileName)) {

            fText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

            foreach (char i in fText) {

                a = ( a + Convert.ToInt32(i)) % MOD_ADLER;
                b = (b + a) % MOD_ADLER;

            }
            int finalValue = (b * ADLER_CONST2 + a);
            output = finalValue.ToString("X");


            lbValue.Text = output.ToString();

        }

        else {

            MessageBox.Show("This is not a valid filepath, or is a blank file.\n" + 
                "Please enter a valid file path.");

        }

    }
```

I understand that this is not an efficient way to go about this, I am just trying to understand what is really going on under the hood. That way I can create a more efficient algorithm that varies from this.

From my understanding. In my code, the example value a is going to be added the integer (32 bit) value plus its initial value of 1. I do the Mod of the very high prime number, and continue moving through the sub-string of my text file adding up the values until all of the characters have been added up.

Comment: You operate on characters. Why don't you operate on bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this two lines confuse you.

```
     a = ( a + Convert.ToInt32(i)) % MOD_ADLER;
     b = (b + a) % MOD_ADLER;
```

Every char have integer representation. You can check this [article](http://www.asciitable.com/). You are changing the value a to be the reminder-> from current value of a + int representetion of the char divided by  MOD_ADLER. You can read [operator %](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

What is reminder: 5%2 = 1

After that you are making same thing for b. b is equal to the reminder current value of b+a divided by MOD_ADLER. After you do that multiple times ( number of chars in the string). You have this.

```
        int finalValue = (b * ADLER_CONST2 + a);
        output = finalValue.ToString("X");
```

This converts the final integer value to HEX.

Comment: So, from what you can see. Am I doing anything in correctly? That could cause an error with my calculations? The results that I am getting aren't coming out correctly, I am really not sure what I am missing or doing wrong in this case. The conversion to hex seems to be working fine. (as it should since that is in C#) but the line.

        `int finalValue = (b * ADLER_CONST2 + a);`

seems to give me a different result than expected. I am using [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) as a reference for values.

Comment: Your question is what is doing this code, not what is the error in my calculations. If you have another question ask it with proper example.

Comment: Well, thank you for explaining the code. It did clear up some grey areas.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = finalValue.ToString("X");
```

The "X" format says generate the hexadecimal represent of the number!

See MSDN [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I understand that as well. However when i get into dealing with large text files like more than a word basically. It seems like my algorithm fails.

Comment: Sorry but that is not your question!